# Example of "convergent" sequences with a new definition

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence. We say $(x_n)$ *converges* to $L$

> if $\exists$ $a>0$ for which there is some $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - L| < a$ for all $n>n'$

I am trying to find sequences which converge under this definition. for example, I claim $x_n = (-1)^n \to 1 $. Lets check it. Take $a = 3$ and $n'  = 1$. Then

$$ |(-1)^n - 1| = \begin{cases} 2 \; \; \; n = 2k+1 \\ 0 \; \; \; n = 2k \end{cases} $$

Thus, both cases, we see that $|x_n-1| < a $ for all $n > 1$. Thus, it works!

Actually, any sequence which converges under the $\mathbf{usual}$ definition also converges under this. Is this correct?

Comment: Your definition of 'convergence' is in fact equivalent to what is usually called as 'boundedness'. So yes, any convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: yes, because you weak **for all $a>0$** to there exists one ... These are just bounded sequences ...

Comment: I think any *bounded* sequence converges under this definition. Since a (usually) convergent sequence is bounded, it too will converge.

Comment: You're right. The example you provide "converges" as does every sequence that converges.

Comment: The definition says $|x_n-L|\lt a$ but you only showed $|x_n-1|\lt a.$ How do you know that $L=1$?

Comment: $L$ is a free variable in the definition? Are we supposed to understand it as $\exists L$ or $\forall L\exists a$ or $\exists a\forall L$?

Comment: bof I edited the question. So, under this definition, sequences actually can converge to two different limits right?

Comment: @ProbabilityGuy I would say that any bounded sequence converges to every real number under this definition.

Comment: Where did you find such definition?

Comment: Tomorrow we will define convergence to mean divergence.

Comment: zhw whay do u mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems correct, though by that definition any bounded sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ (say bounded by M) converges to any number $L$. Just take $a=M+1+|L|$, $n'=1$. Then if $n>n'$, $|x_n-L|\leq |x_n|+|L| < M+1+|L|=a$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Try to prove that a sequence converges under this definition if and only if it is bounded.

Your observation is true since convergent implies bounded.